# tuple error in hangman game

Tags: python, tuples

this snippet of code comes from my hangman game and as i am not entirely sure what a tuple error is and how to solve it i have come here.

```
Continue = input("Do you want to play hangman?").lower()
while Continue == ("y", "ye", "yes", "yeah").lower():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print ("Hello, " + name, "Time to play hangman! You have ten guesses to win!")
    print ("\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    difficulty()
else:
    quit
```

when i input this code i get the error:

> ```
> while Continue == ("y", "ye", "yes", "yeah").lower():
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: The error you posted does not match your code (although lists don't expose a `lower()` method either).

Comment: The answer posted answers the immediate problem of how to avoid the error message, but you have more problems.  You only request the user input `Continue` once, so the `while` loop will either execute infinitely, or never.

Comment: `while` should be replaced by `if` .. since there is an `else` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Means that a tuple (like `(1, 2, 3)`) cannot be `lower`cased because lowercasing only makes sense for a `str`ing.

You probably meant:

```
while Continue in ("y", "ye", "yes", "yeah"):
```

Comment: Is the lower() even needed? The input is being converted to lowercase so maybe just `while Continue in ("y", "ye", "yes", "yeah"):` should be enough

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues of course is not, I had not seen the line above :)